# groovy: adding and removing elements from a defined variable within a class

Tags: list, groovy

I'm trying to get this class to run but I keep running into issues. I'm new to Java and not sure if I am doing this correctly. If someone could just help me out with the addition of elements to a list I can figure out the rest!

```
class ListPractice implements Testable {

    def mylist = [4,5,6]

    /**
     * Adds a set of elements to the mylist variable
     *
     * @param elts The elements to be added
     */
    def addToList(List elts) {

        def newlist = getMylist()+List
        return newlist
    }

    @Override
    void testMe() {
        addToList([7,8,9])
        assert  getMylist() == [4,5,6,7,8,9]
        assert  getMylist() == [7,8,9]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `List` instead of `elts`.  The method you are looking for is `addAll`:

```
groovy:000> l = [1,2,3]
===> [1, 2, 3]
groovy:000> l.addAll([4,5,6])
===> true
groovy:000> l
===> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Since `addtoList` sounds already as if you plan to mutate `this`, why create a
new one, return it, and later never use it?  So: `mylist.addAll(elts)` should
be enough.

related:

- just write `mylist` instead of `getMylist()` - it's groovy
- your comment on `addToList` says `set` but accepys a `list`. Sets have
  different characteristics than lists, so it's confusing.  If you rename it
  to `addToMylist` you might not even need a comment at all.